# Unable to bind HTML elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax function which retrieves list of all the products from the database which i want to show on the website

Ajax call is working properly, the problem is i am unable to bind elements on a particular div at runtime. However i can get all items in alert box.

Here's my Ajax jQuery call:

```
function GenerateList()
{
    if (getCookie("AnonymousBasket") != "")
    {
        var Records;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: "Section_v1.aspx/GetAnonymousBasketItems",         // Location of the service
            data: "{'AnonymousBasketID' : '" + $.trim(getCookie("AnonymousBasket")) + "'}",         //Data sent to server
            contentType: "application/json",        // content type sent to server
            dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
            processdata: true,  //True or False
            async : false,
            success: function (data) {//On Successful service call
                if (data.d.TotalRecordCount > 0) {
                    $(".myNewCart").append("<ul>");
                    $.each(data.d.Records, function (index, item) {
                        $(".myNewCart").append("<li>" + GenerateHTML(item.PackageInfo.ProductsInfo.ImagePath, item.PackageInfo.ProductsInfo.Name, item.PurchasedUnits, item.PackageInfo.SabkaSupermarketPrice, parseInt(parseInt(item.PurchasedUnits) * parseInt(item.PackageInfo.SabkaSupermarketPrice))) + "</li>");
                    })
                }
            },
            error: function (json) {
                alert("Error: " + json.status);
            }// When Service call fails
        });


    }
}
GenerateList();
```

Here's my Div on the master page:

```
<div class="myNewCart"></div>
```

Webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static object GetAnonymousBasketItems(Guid AnonymousBasketID)
    {
        List<Entities.AnonymousBasket> cart = basket.GetProductsFromAnonymousBasket(AnonymousBasketID);
        int productCount = cart.Count;
        //List<Entities.AnonymousBasket> filteredProducts = cart.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
        return new { Result = "OK", Records = cart, TotalRecordCount = productCount };
    }
```

I could not figure out why its not binding.

Comment: 1. `Records` is never assigned but you try to iterate through it...???

Comment: Sorry it was posting typo, however i have used it properly in code. also now i have posted webmethod

Answer (score 0):

Your $.each is using "Records" to populate the div whereas ajax data is being retrieved in the "data" field.

Comment: Sorry it was posting typo, however i have used it properly in code. also now i have posted webmethod.

Comment: Can you post the Json response obtained from the server by examining your chrome developer tool/Firefox's firebug window?

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolution, everything was in place just the problem was the `<div>` tag being placed after the `javascript` call, so script was unable to find the div

I placed the script at the footer of the page and it worked.

Anyways thanks all for helping me.

Comment: if you got the solution for the question asked, kindly marked it as accepted so that it can help others to recognize the most accurate answer